# How to replace string using ltrim in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

code:

I have created an autocomplete text box which works fine but the problem is that I have multiple values of `skill_input` like:

```
Noida | hotel paradise
Noida | Your Dream
Delhi | Radission
uttar pradesh | hotel Nimbus
uttar pradesh | Krishna Hotel
```

These are the some values when I keyup on autocomplete text box. Now, What I want when I select `Noida | hotel paradise` so `Noida |` this string should be removed only `hotel paradise` should be redirect. Similarly other values I want only those value which are occuring after `|` symbol. So, How can I do this? Please help me.

```
$("#w_t_g").autocomplete({
    source: "search.php",
    select: function (event, ui) 
    {
        $("#skill_input").val(ui.item.id);
        str = ui.item.value;
        a = str.replace(/[ |]+/g, "+");
        window.location.href="hotel_search.php?result=" + a;
    }
});
```

Thank You

Comment: use `Regex()` to replace or remove duplicate string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use split function:

```
$("#w_t_g").autocomplete({
    source: "search.php",
    select: function (event, ui) 
    {
        $("#skill_input").val(ui.item.id);
        str = ui.item.value;
        a = str.split(" | ")[1];
        window.location.href="hotel_search.php?result=" + a;
    }
});
```